# What happens to the atoms and their constituents when we break something ?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atoms

My query is: how does an atom stable itself. When we break something, what actually happens in the chemical bonding of its atoms, does it rupture or remain intact?

Answer (score 1):

Usually a structure consists of molecules bonded together with intermolecular bonds. Intermolecular bonds can be through the van der waals force, dipole bonds, or hydrogen bridges.

When an object breaks, these intermolecular bonds are broken. This is also the reason some objects break more easily than others; when the intermolecular bonds are weaker, they are easier to overcome and your object will break more easily.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of bonds that exist between atoms and molecules, intramolecular bonds and intermolecular bonds. Intramolecular bonds exist between atoms, and they are responsible for the existence of molecules, and they occur when electrons are moved form one atom to another, which results in the stabilization of electron orbitals. The electrons can move totally, or partially from one atom to another. In the first case we have an ionic bond, and in the second, we have a covalent bond. Both are much stronger than the intermolecular bonds. Because intramolecular bonds last much longer than intermolecular bonds, which form and break all the time, intermolecular bonds are often not characterized as bonds. Intermolecular bonds form between molecules, and have various forms: dipole-dipole ,dipolе-ion, induced dipole-ion ,induced dipole-dipole and induced dipole-induced dipole  interactions. All are much weaker than intramolecular forces.

When you cut or break something, you usually break only the intermolecular forces. It is energetically more beneficial, (you use less energy) to cut weak bonds than strong bonds. But when you break or cut something, you can also break the strong covalent bonds. Because covalent bonds are formed with electron exchange, when you break them, electrons can distribute themselves between the two ends. There are two options: homolytic and heterolytic bond breaking. In homolytic cleavage, electrons distribute equally between the atoms that made that bond, and you end up with radicals. In heterolytic cleavage more electrons end up on one atom, and you end up with ions.

For example: Your nails consist of a protein polymer. Those polymers consist of long chains of covalently bonded amino-acids. When you cut your nails, in addition to breaking intermolecular bonds, you also break the covalently bonded amino-acids.

Look up on wikipedia: chemical bond, intermolecular forces, bond cleavage.